# How to get pagemthods value in the calling function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to fetch current year from the server using PageMethods but PageMethods returns result in different function but i want to get the return value in the same function where PageMthods is called. Is it possible?

```
function GetYear()
{
     dr["OrderYear"] = PageMethods.GetCurrentYear(Onsuccess);
}

function Onsuccess(currYear)
{
   alert(currYear);
}

 [WebMethod]
    public static string GetCurrentYear()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.Year.ToConvertedString();
    }
```

I want currYear to be assigned to  dr["OrderYear"] which is actually  a calling function

Comment: what is the signature of `GetCurrentYesr()` and are you allowed to change it?

Comment: added cs code which contains signature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

The PageMethods proxy class is asynchronous (which is the A in AJAX, after all).  You can condense the code a bit with an anonymous callback function though:

```
function GetYear() {
  PageMethods.GetCurrentYear(function(currentYear) {
    alert(currentYear);

    dr["OrderYear"] = currentYear;

    // Etc.
  });
}
```